# How do you detect whether the calling thread of a function is already RTAI real-time?

Tags: linux, real-time, rtai, lxrt

I am working on a big project that uses RTAI both in kernel and user spaces. I won't get into the details of the project, but here is briefly where a problem arises.

In user-space, my project provides a library used by other people to write some software. Those programs themselves may have RTAI real-time threads.

Now, some functions in RTAI require that their calling thread have already `rt_thread_init`ed so if I want to use them in a function in the library, I need to temporarily make the calling thread real-time by calling `rt_thread_init` and later `rt_task_delete`.

Now here's the problem:

If the calling thread of my function IS already real-time, then I am `rt_thread_init`ing which I assume simply fails, but then I `rt_task_delete` and make that thread non-real-time (besides the fact that when the thread itself (assuming I changed nothing) again `rt_task_delete`s, RTAI crashes.

If the calling thread of my function IS not real-time, everything is ok.

For now, I resorted to taking a parameter in the function so that the calling function tells the library if it is real-time or not. However, **I wanted to know if RTAI has a function or something so I could use to automatically detect whether the current thread is real-time or not.**

Don't know if there are any RTAI users here (I certainly didn't see the RTAI tag), but hope there would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried it myself, so this is a guess - but did you consider using rt_whoami?

> Get the task pointer of the current task.

https://www.rtai.org/documentation/magma/html/api/api_8c.html#a12

I would imagine it will fail (return NULL?) if you are in a non RT task...

Comment: It was really a desperate act to ask this in stack overflow, but I'm glad I did! Take this +1 for now until Monday that I go try it

Comment: You know, turns out `rt_whoami` is only in kernel space and `rt_buddy`, according to the maintainer of RTAI is the replacement, although he said it's only good for debugging. However, the email I read this from was from 2003 and `rt_buddy` is not in the documentations either. I have asked to see whether this is still true.